# What is the terminology of an argument by gradually getting rid of other possibilities?

Tags: terminology

In a game show, a player has to guess the answer from a quiz of 4 options. He manages to find the answer by considering the first option, then argues that it is not the case. Then he does the same for the options 2 and 3. He then concludes that the answer is the option 4.

In English, how do we call this type of argument?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally, this sounds like "He figured out the answer by process of elimination." BTW, if you have to "guess" the answer, you can't reason your way to it.  The contestant must "pick," "choose" or "select" an answer from the available choices.

Comment: What is the term for it in your native language?

Comment: Colloquially, it's "weeding out" the list of options.

Answer (score 2):

**process of elimination**  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/elimination?q=process%20of%20elimination)
​

> by removing from several possible answers the ones that are unlikely
>   to be correct until only one is left

As in:

> We eventually found the answer by a process of elimination.